# How to make Rails app asynchronous in JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, jruby

I've read some tutorials that how to make Rails app asynchronous to improve the application throughput:

http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/improving-application-throughput-900-percent-with-asynchronous-responses-in-rails-3.html

https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails

None of them works in JRuby. I know that Rails/JRuby handles concurrency better than MRI, but I don't know how to do it.

What is the right approach for this in JRuby?

Answer (score 0):

Since JRuby is running on JVM, it can scale pretty well, just out of the box. So a simple and quite cheap solution would be to throw some more resources at it. Nowadays hosting providers have many different hosting plans, so it might be a case of a few extra bucks a month.

Also you could leverage a power of async web servers like [Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) or [Puma](http://puma.io/) and for example create web services for the parts of your RoR application which require to serve many connections per second.

Finally, there is pretty good article touching async web servers and performance topics. You can find it here: [Web technologies for speed up](http://www.businesstechnologyarticles.eu/web-technologies-for-speed-up)

Comment: Thank you for the link [Web technologies for speed up](http://www.businesstechnologyarticles.eu/web-technologies-for-speed-up)